# Options not rendering on Sprout Reports report

Tags: templating

My Sprout Report I just set up is not rendering the "options" template.

The results and options template both exists, and have been copied from the examples directory that came with Sprout Forms. This options template is rendered on the build in "Users and User Groups" report - but not on mine.

The only difference is my report has a data source of "Custom Twig Template" as opposed to "Users" - but that shouldn't matter.

[The docs](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/reports/docs/custom-reports/custom-twig-template-report) and the built in examples aren't shedding any light on the situation. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I believe the issue may be that you have included the file extension `.twig`. Can you try removing that and see if that gets things working? So: `_reports/dealer-export/options`. I'll add it to our list to be smarter about that if that's the case.

Comment: Ah, that was totally it Ben. If you want to put that in as an answer I'll mark that as the accepted one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that the Results Template and Options Template include the file extension `.twig`. Removing the extension `.twig` should get things working:

```
_reports/dealer-export/options
```

I've added it to our list to improve this functionality in the future. We should be able to strip off the extension behind the scenes or do what we need to do with it regardless of whether you add it or not. Sprout Reports does loop through and check for all supported extension types for your site on the back end when no extension is provided.